# How do I convert this pcre regex to be used with Oracle's REGEXP_SUBSTR?

Tags: regex, oracle, pcre

I have this `pcre` regular expression that I want to port to an Oracle-supported regex:

`^.*pdf_(\w+-\w+).*$`

Is designed to match and only what's bolded:

> roundBox indent pdf_**placement**
>
> pdf_**grade**
>
> indent pdf_**placement1** roundBox

What is the equivalent expression in Oracle's regex syntax?

**Edit:**

I tried what was suggested by `sln` in the comments:

`SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(class, '^.*pdf_(\w+(?:-\w+)*).*$') FROM ...`

And all I'm getting is the entire value returned, not just the match:

```
roundBox indent pdf_placement
```

instead of

```
placement
```

Comment: The syntax is basic regex, should be transportable.

Comment: But, if you want to be specific, a good sub-expression there is (`\w+(?:-\w+)*)`

Comment: @sln Oracle does not support non-capturing groups.

Comment: @MT0 - Does Oracle produce a regex engine of it's own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression I ended up going with was:

`pdf_(\w+(?-\w*)*)`

In full, the `SELECT` clause looked like this:

`SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(class, 'pdf_(\w+(-\w*)*)', 1, 1, 'i', 1) FROM ...`

Comment: And the slightly faster version of it `pdf_(\w+(-\w?)*)`

Answer (score 0):

You could take the approach of replacing what's unwanted:

```
SQL> with t (txt) as (
  2  select 'roundBox indent pdf_placement' from dual union all
  3  select 'PDF_grade' from dual union all
  4  select 'indent pdf_placement1 roundBox' from dual
  5  ) -- end of sample data
  6  select regexp_replace(txt, '^.*pdf_(\w+).*$', '\1', 1, 0, 'i')
  7    from t;
REGEXP_REPLACE(TXT,'^.*PDF_(\W
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
placement
grade
placement1
```

I used the parameter 'i' to make it case insensitive and work with capital letters PDF as well. Feel free to play with it as needed.